# How to get column names from a cassandra column family in ruby client.?

Tags: ruby, cassandra

I use ruby client to access data from Cassandra.. Is there any way to get the column names for a given key in a column family.
Suppose a column family "test" has 100 rows with rows having different column names. SO given a key how do I get the column names for that key??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the `'cassandra'` gem then you would do something like this:

```
@client.get(:my_column_family, key).keys
```

`@client.get` returns an ordered hash of `column_name => column_value` so `.keys` will give you the column_names.

If you are using the `'cassandra-cql'` gem:

```
@client.execute("select * from my_column_family where key = ?", key).fetch.column_names
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.. But doing "multiget" wont be a overhead?? My column value is around 5KB and there are around 5-6 columns for a key.. so everytime it will get ~30KB of data which is big.. is there not any other way to get only the keys??

Comment: There is no API for fetching only column names. If you really think that the overhead is going to be a problem then you could have a separate column family that only stores the column names.